# How suitable is this example question for the main site?

Tags: discussion

Would this be suitable as a question on Ask Different?

**Using A Combination of Android & iOS Devices in Everyday Digital Life?**

I have often heard the phrase, if you own an iOS device that is what you should stick to, in order to immerse yourself & harmonise your activities within Apple's ecosystem.

Similarly if you own an Android smartphone, you should own an Android tablet in order to immerse yourself & harmonise your activities within the Android/Google Ecosystem.

Whilst this makes perfect sense to me......

If one were to combine an iDevice, either iPhone or iPad with an Android device (either smartphone or tablet), and therefore immersing yourself in both worlds.

Is one giving oneself additional hassle in everyday life with such an arrangement (as opposed to just to sticking to one or the other) ?

Comment: Also - don't be too discouraged by down votes here on meta. They don't dock your reputation and indicate that others feel the proposal isn't appropriate for the main site (or up votes would indicate it's a good thing). The good thing is to ask and start a dialog +10 for that

Comment: @bmike Thats fine. I guess thats the whole point of Meta !

Comment: @bmike I just came across this right now http://gizmodo.com/how-to-use-android-and-ios-together-1358600762

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem to run afoul of the guidelines to have a practical question.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

What specific problem would you be trying to solve by asking a question like the one you proposed?

Comment: Thought as much. Its not specific. Would like advice/feedback regarding the complexities of juggling different devices rather than keeping them all iOS or Android. If you see my point.

Comment: The site isn't really suited for advice/feedback. It's designed for asking a question that has a correct answer.

Comment: @DanielLawson Yes its not a forum - but rather a specific question with a specific answer (although generally there is more than one way to answer a question).

Comment: @DanielLawson Do you know of any suitable places I could ask ?

Comment: The chat room is a good place for these discussions. You could even make a room for that topic if enough people had things to say.

Comment: @bmike Sounds like a good idea. I often forget about the chat facility at SE.

Comment: @Simon I think you could ask any number of valid questions pertaining to the topic on the site. The problem is with unanswerable *tell me everything* questions (or as I think of them, *essay questions*). Try making a list of your concerns for yourself, then post a question about one specific issue. It still might not fly, but I think there is value here — and potential blogpost fodder.

Comment: @jaberg Thanks for that. I think there are quite a few people out there who mix and match, for the simple reason, they like getting their finger in all the pies, instead of making life simple and sticking with one or the other.